# Conditions under which $\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ will be rational.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, rational-numbers

Suppose $x$ is an irrational number and $a,b,c,d$ are rational numbers. If we know that 
$$
\frac{(ax+b)}{(cx+d)}
$$
is rational, then it follows that:

a.) $a=c=0$,

b.) $a=c$ and $b=d$,

c.) $a+b = c+d$,

d.) $ad = bc$

My attempt:  For lack of knowledge, my initial attempt was to try out all the options one by one.  When I came to the option d, I realised that it is a more general form of both option a and b, and since both option a and b were correct I marked the answer as d. However, I am searching for an approach which does not involve trying out all the options.

Comment: note, it is asking you what *must* follow; not what can.  If a =0 and b=0 then the term is rational, but it doesn't have follow that a *must* =0.  As you point out a) is a special case of d).  So a) isn't true (or doesn't have to be)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if the expression has to be rational then $\exists\ r,s\in \mathbb{Z},\ s\ne 0$ with $(r,s)=1$ such that $$\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}=\frac{r}{s}\\\implies (as-cr)x=(dr-bs)\implies ad=bc$$ which comes out from the fact that $x$ is rational whereas $a,b,c,d,r,s$ are rationals.

Comment: You answered $7$ seconds first, and our solutions appear the same. Should I delete mine?

Comment: I don't think you have to delete your answer. I am okay with it. If anybody else gives any objection you can think then.

Comment: @MXYMXY Was mine any different? I too answered at the same time... Only one is enough.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay I could not follow , the last implication i.e. ad = bc . Would you please explain how that comes from the fact that x is irrational while the others are rational.

Comment: Since $x$ is irrational, the equation relating $x$ to the other numbers reads as "irrational"="rational" since the LHS is irrational and the RHS is rational. This can happen only if LHS=RHS=0. Since, $x$ maybe nonzero, in general, we get the equations $as=cr,\ dr=bs$ from which the desired condition follows, using $s\ne 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ is rational, then $ax+b=cpx+dp$, where $p$ is a rational number.

This implies that $(a-cp)x=(b-dp)$, where $x$ is irrational, implying that $a=cp$, $b=dp$. Thus the answer is $ad=bc$.

Comment: If the number is to be rational then it has to be of the form $\frac{p}{q}$ . Here you have assumed that q = 1.Why so, why can't it be of the form where p and q are co primes such that none of them equals one too.

Comment: In your comment you assume $p$ and $q$ are coprime natural numbers. I just said $\frac{m}{n}=p$, so $p$ is not a natural number.

Comment: @SuryakantShrivastava To be clearer, your mistake is that you are assuming that $p$ is a natural number in my answer, when it is a ration of the form $\frac{m}{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{(ax+b)}{(cx+d)}=\frac ac \frac{(x+\frac ba)}{(x+\frac dc)}$

So, if $\frac ba = \frac dc$ , then it will cancel out. That means, $ad=bc$